# Parsing xml file with xpath and xquery using eXist-db

Tags: xml, xpath, exist-db

I need to fetch the `<TITLE>` element from the following XML using XQuery (I'm using eXist-db).

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="shakes.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!--!DOCTYPE PLAY PUBLIC "-//PLAY//EN" "play.dtd"-->
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <PLAY>
        <TITLE>The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark</TITLE>
    </PLAY>
</ClinicalDocument >
```

When I try with the XQuery below I am not getting the expected output.

```
xquery version "3.0";

doc("/db/apps/demo/data/hamlet.xml")/ClinicalDocument/PLAY/TITLE
```

I think the problem is related to the `xmlns` attribute present in the `<ClinicalDocument>` tag:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
```

How can I modify my XQuery to retrieve the desired XML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a prefix that mapped to your XML default namespace, and use that prefix to reference elements in the namespace, something like this :

```
declare namespace d = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
doc("/db/apps/demo/data/hamlet.xml")/d:ClinicalDocument/d:PLAY/d:TITLE
```

tested here : http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/a88f300bbeacdbd846d7aec887d48a0b

Comment: actually the tag contain multiple attributes like this,<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd">

Comment: That's not significant as long as your XPath expression doesn't include elements prefixed with those other namespace prefixes

Comment: ok. now this is my result,<title xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">Continuity of Care Document</title>  how can i get exact value,by avoiding the title tag also?

Comment: add `/text()` at the end, or `/string(.)`

Comment: Thank you .one more to ask, what if we don;t know the namespace value, or if we need to fetch from different namespace.?

Comment: Not sure, maybe using `namespace-uri(/*)` to query namespace URI of the root element..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102953/discussion-between-arun-m-r-nair-and-har07).

Answer (score 1):

For any namespace, you can use the * wildcard in place of the namespace prefix.

So if you just want the text of the title, you can do:

```
doc("/db/apps/demo/data/hamlet.xml")/*:ClinicalDocument/*:PLAY/*:TITLE/text()
```

There is no longer the need to define the namespace. (Although you'll find that having a defined schema with a namespace makes working with XQuery much nicer in the long run.)